# Bootstrap Tabs preventDefault() breaks dropdown functionality

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, dropdown, preventdefault

there's this nice little snippet for Bootstrap around here which prevents jumping of tabs after a click:

```
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
        $('.tab-content > .tab-pane.active').jScrollPane();
        window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
    })

    $('.nav-tabs li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
        $('.tab-content > .tab-pane.active').jScrollPane();
    });
```

Unfortunately it is preventing the default behavior of da dropdown-tab.
The result is that you can't click any of the links within the dropdown.

How can I solve this.
I'd like to inherit this to all tabs. So an override for Bootstrap without adding custom classes or ids would be nice.

Thanks for your help.
monsee

Answer (score 0):

i've got a solution. Just check if the current elements class is not equal to 'dropdown-toggle' also delete the second block with the clicked-event. Seems to work:

```
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle') {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
        $('.tab-content > .tab-pane.active').jScrollPane();
    }
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
})
```